# Can you Unit Test a method using Moq without having to create a test subject?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I have the below method that is a simple unit test for a method using Moq. If my understanding is correct, I have to create the *ProductServiceTestSubject* class in order to provide a test subject. I've only been experimenting with Moq for an hour or so, so it may be I am overlooking functionality. Is there any way I would be able to achieve the same as below **without** having to create the additional test subject class?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckoutWithDiscountCallsTheDiscountAction()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<ProductService> mockProductSvc = new Mock<ProductService>();

        mockProductSvc.SetupGet(p => p.IsDiscounted).Returns(true);
        mockProductSvc.Setup(p => p.DoDiscountAction()).Verifiable();

        // Act
        ProductServiceTestSubject.Checkout(mockProductSvc.Object);

        // Assert
        mockProductSvc.Verify();
    }

    public class ProductServiceTestSubject
    {
        public static void Checkout(IProductService productService)
        {
            productService.Checkout();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Here is the same method without the requirement of the additional test subject class:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void CheckoutWithDiscountCallsTheDiscountAction()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<ProductService> mockProductSvc = new Mock<ProductService>() { CallBase = true };

        mockProductSvc.SetupGet(p => p.IsDiscounted).Returns(true);
        mockProductSvc.Setup(p => p.DoDiscountAction()).Verifiable();

        // Act
        mockProductSvc.Object.Checkout();

        // Assert
        mockProductSvc.Verify();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `CallBase`.  From the [Customizing Mock Behavior](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Customizing_Mock_Behavior) section of the quick start:

> Invoke base class implementation if no expectation overrides the
>   member (a.k.a. "Partial Mocks" in Rhino Mocks): default is false.
>   (this is required if you are mocking Web/Html controls in System.Web!)

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo> { CallBase = true };
```

So in your code,

```
// Arrange
Mock<ProductService> mockProductSvc = new Mock<ProductService> { CallBase = true };

...

// Act
mockProductSvc.Object.Checkout();
```